# Can't connect to wireless network at home with OS X 10.5.8

Tags: wifi, airport

I'm having trouble connecting to the wireless network at my home. My brother recently picked up a new wireless router and provided me with the password. When I locate the SSID and enter in the password he told me, it waits for a few seconds then says "Connection Failed."

I can connect to the wifi on my iPhone 4 but because I do a lot of work from my Mac running OS X 10.5.8, it's imperative that I can connect to the wifi on my laptop. I can connect to other wifi networks (in fact, I'm at a Starbucks using their wifi right now).

I don't think it has anything to do with my Mac, but if it does, can anyone provide any insight or solution?

If it's with the router, how can I configure it to allow me to connect with my Mac?

Comment: What kind of router is it? Does it work if your brother briefly sets up a password-less WLAN (just for testing)?

Comment: I'm not at home right now, but I can find out what kind of router it is later tonight; as well as test if I can connect password-less. Thanks for the suggestion! Will get back to you (and anybody else) soon :)

Comment: The router is an Actiontec V1000H I think... Also tried connecting with no password and it still says connection failed... Thoughts?

Comment: After logging into the modem interface, i seemed to made things worst...i updated the security from WPA/WPA2-Personal to simply "WPA-2 personal". now the wifi connection can't be found at all!

Comment: → QLe: To correctly analyse your problem, I'd advise you to fix a few details:
1) On your Actiontec router, choose a fixed 802.11b channel, usually not overloaded by automatic default configurations: **channel 5**
2) Choose a fixed and always working network name: **AAAAAAAA**
3) Choose a fixed and always working authentication method: **No password**

Comment: → QLe: could you open `Apple > About This Mac > More Info…`, select `Network > AirPort`
and add to your original question the following details:
`Supported PHY Modes:`
`Supported Channels:`
Current Network Information:
`PHY Mode:`
`Channel:`
`Security:`
`Signal / Noise:`

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be caused by a SSID which contains special signs (e.g. - / ! : %)

Comment: Just FYI, this is more of a comment than an answer. If you think this is the case (whether or not it is) please provide a way for the OP to resolve the problem, or repost this as a comment. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Soxman, yes I realized the mistake I made as soon as I clicked submit. FYI, the issue still isn't resolved. So again here are some items that might help: Modem: Motorola S5100 (I think) / Router: Actiontec V1000H / SSID was Valefor / I knew what the password was / I logged into the modem interface and updated the security from WPA or WPA2-personal to just WPA2-personal. After that, I could no longer even find the connection. We are attempting to reset the router back to factory settings. I assume tho, that even after this, I'll still be unable to connect to the wifi with my mac. Thoughts?

Comment: I was correct in my assumption. The router settings were reset and the wifi connection was reestablished . however, like before the wifi connection can be found, but whenever i try connecting it says "connection failed" (FYI not "invalid password"). I appreciate all tips who thinks they know the problem is. Thanks all!